# Value returned from <select> using jQuery has a (.) at the beginning and end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a dropdown box, of which when a value is selected it is printed on the console.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#id").change(function() {
    var myVar = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
    console.log(myVar);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id">
  <option value="any">Any</option>
  <option value="value">Value</option>
</select>
```

The output is `.value.` .

But when replaced the `val()` with `text()`

The output is `value`.

Please help understand this issue.

Comment: not able to reproduce

Comment: It's working as expected. The .val() gets this value   <option value="`value`">Value</option>. And when you use .text it gets this value   <option value="value">`Value`</option>. What's wrong with that. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: None of the results that you say you get are what this code produces.

Comment: could it be an issue with the browser? Or could it be jQuery 2.0.0?

Comment: Please confirm is it the exact code, or the dropdown is populating through database values?

Comment: Braike dp, Why are you asking if the problem could be with jQuery 2.0.0 when in the code posted you use jQuery 3.1.1 ?? Please post the exact code !

Comment: data is populated from DB. but the values in DB is correct . page source shows correct value.

Comment: @EduardoJunior because the jQuery version i'm using is `jquery-2.0.0.min.js`. It was bundled with the free template i'm using.

Comment: @EduardoJunior sorry, the script incldued in the question was added my Mr Greek from stackoverflow.

Comment: @Braikedp, no, you added the script yourself. All that Mr Geek did, was make it runnable. The code is exactly what you posted. The problem you describe cannot be reproduced. Please edit your question to give us a reproducible scenario.

Comment: @Braikedp you could check if the data returned is properly encoded - perhaps the dot is a result of invisible characters present in the database or while sending down the data it is not sent as say ASCII or UTF

Comment: *"page source shows correct value"*: when you do `.val()` you don't get what the page shows, but what is in the `value` attribute. In your question you show that `value="value"`. But what you describe suggests that this is not the case. It seems like you really have `value=".value."`. Did you really verify that?

Comment: @trincot yes. thats what I actually meant by the page source shows correct value. the `.val()` is printed in the console.

Comment: Then, it is now your job to create a fiddle that *produces* this output when `value` is like you say it is. We need to see it.

Comment: `<option value='Audi'>Audi</option>                                                                <option value='BMW'>BMW</option>` This the pagesource output of the data retrieved from DB.

Comment: That is not a fiddle. We need something that can run. Because if I put that snippet of HTML in my browser, it does not produce what you tell us.